# Disappearing Form in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm new to Access and VBA so this must have a simple solution but I can't debug it. Basically I'm opening a form by clicking a button in another form. Form A has a list of invoices, each with a button that when clicked goes to the invoice itself (form B).

Problem is that when I FIRST click on the button in form A first, I go to the invoice, no problem. However, if I click again (can be same invoice) I go to a to a BLANK form. Nothing there. Zip, zilch, nada.

I can click as many times as I want but it opens the blank invoice. By blank I don't mean a form with unpopulated fields. I mean NOTHING, no fields no anything. See below screen grabs.

But here is the kicker: IF I do something to the vba script on the invoice page (included below) even something as silly as putting in an extra EMPTY LINE, then it works again for 1 time. After that, I get the blank invoice again.

I have no idea how to debug this. Note that I removed just about everything on the invoice form to be sure it wasn't something else. All I left is a check if we're in a new record as I'd like to autopopulate some fields.

Is this a corruption issue with the db, is it a programming issues... Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

```
'this is what form B, my invoice form has
Option Compare Database


Private Sub Form_Load()


If Me.NewRecord Then


MsgBox "we're in a new record"
End If


End Sub
```

This is my invoice list
[image: invoiceList]

I hit goto first time and end up here (invoice list stays open)
[image: 1st hit]

This is what happens when I hit goto the 2nd time and after. I go to a blank page... nothing. No field etc
[image: 2nd and after hits]

Comment: With that second form in Design View, check its "Allow Additions" property.  If it's No, change to Yes.  Does that change what you see when the form is subsequently opened in Form View?

Comment: @HansUp You're totally right! Should have figured that one out myself but I thought I'd get an error or a locked page, didn't know the result would be blank :) Any idea why it would go to next record even though it does a search for the same id number? Thank you!

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with how you're opening the second form.  Can't say more based on what you've shown us.  However you did show `Option Compare Database`, but `Option Explicit` is not there.  I believe it is a mistake to spend any time trouble-shooting VBA code which does not include `Option Explicit`.